# Good practices to bind OSGi services in a 0..n cardinality?

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

Let's say that I have a bundle that wants to broadcast an information to all its listeners. Considering that I'm using declarative services in which `MyComponent` is consuming 0..n `ComponentListeners`, I would have something like this:

```
public class MyComponent {

    private List<ComponentListener> listeners;
    private String data;

    public MyComponent() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // Someone else will call this
    public void updateData(String newData) {
        data = newData;
        notifyAll(data);
    }

    // Broadcasts the data to all listeners
    private void notifyAll(String data) {
        for (ComponentListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.updateData(data);
        }
    }

    // Declarative Service binding methods
    public void bindComponentListener(ComponentListener cl) {
        listeners.add(cl);
    }

    public void unbindComponentListener(ComponentListener cl) {
        listeners.remove(cl);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is the 0..n cardinality recommended? The only example that I have found was from an [Apache Felix tutorial](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-tutorial-example-8.html), which is similar to the one above.
2. Is the observer/observable approach considered a good practice in OSGi?
3. If I want to notify all listeners, I should call `listener.updateData(data);` in a different thread for each listener, right? This way, I'm ensuring that all listeners will be notified at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main goal is to broadcast information you might also use the OSGi Event Admin, felix has a [quick tutorial](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-event-admin.html) as well. Handling your own listeners via Services might be [considered harmful](http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/Links/whiteboard.pdf).

Comment: I was completely forgetting about the Event Admin, but before trying something with this, I will read the full paper first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing observers by letting other bundles implement and publish the listener service is a good practice in OSGi.
Also using declarative services to manage the list works well. 
The only thing I am not sure of is if it makes sense to use one thread for each listener. The problem is that you create a lot of threads and a lot of load on the system. This might also scale badly for many listeners. So alternatives are to just use the same thread or to use a thread pool. The thread pool will limit the load on the system and so make your approach more scalable.

Comment: Also the shown code is not thread-safe but perhaps you left that out for simplicity-of-example in this question. Even using multiple threads provides no guarantee of notification of all the listeners at the "same time".

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in implementing a thread pool to limit the load because I wouldn't know how many listeners will receive the notification. Actually, I just want to avoid having a listener that would take long to handle the notification, as this would delay the other listeners.
However, as mentioned by apf7188, it might be a good idea to use the Event Admin, isn't it?

Comment: The good thing with event admin is that you do not have to manage the listeners. The bad thing is that event admin sends key value pairs. So the interface looks less object oriented.